# Update Field in workflow to previous value

Tags: workflow

I want that if Profile of User is not `system administrator` then if the user updates `Title` field of `User Object` then it does not get updated or updates to its previous value. 
For this I created a workflow, on User object having :

```
Evaluation criteria : created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

and Rule Criteria : Run this when following formula evaluates to true
```

Formula is : `Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'`

and in `New Field Update` I have chosen `Title` in field to update.

and in Specify New Field Value I have written this in formula field `priorvalue(title)`

Workflow rule is active. But the user is still able to change the title. Where I am going wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Validation rule instead of a workflow. A workflow would be fired after a successful update, which I don't think will work in your case.

You typically want the update to be prevented due to not meeting certain conditions, which is exactly what a validation rule is used for.

Comment: Thanks @AslamK for the answer, but I dont want to show any error. I am able to do it using trigger but I want to try it using workflow.

Comment: Workflows are generally not for trapping errors. They are for doing certain actions on successful updates. To trap errors you need to go with a trigger or a validation rule.

Comment: So you mean we cannot do this by workflow? I am just curious. I am new to SFDC.

Comment: Correct. I dont think you can use it. Since I am not sure if PRIORVALUE will actually contain the old value during the field update.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it’s edited

Rule Criteria   ISCHANGED( Title ) && NOT($Profile.Name = "System Administrator")

Keep the field update to - priorvalue(title)